# how to get common numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Table Secondary Sales. in which i have column like `Cust_Code`,`Transaction_Date`.

in last three month i want to find out which `Cust_code` is common.

if i run this query

```
select distinct Stockist_Code
from ZSecondarySales 
where Tran_date = '2018-12-31' and  Tran_date ='2019-01-31' and Tran_date = '2019-02-28';
```

then i get 132 records.

but there can be `cust_code` like `In dec 100 cust_code`. `In Jan 110 cust_code`. `In Feb 115 cust_code`.

I want find only common Customer numbers not whole Custmer number.

Comment: how do you define it is common?

Comment: That i want to find out

Comment: That first query can never work. How can `Tran_date` equal 3 different dates at the same time? Did you mean `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: I want to find only those records which are present in every three months

Comment: If a number present in jan and not in feb then it should take that records.

Comment: If a record present in dec jan and feb then only fetch that record

Comment: Can you show an example of the table and the result you're trying to get? It's hard to understand from the question.

Comment: @ShahabHaidar try putting OR instead of AND in the query as Barmar suggested

Comment: `select Stockist_Code
from ZSecondarySales 
where Tran_date in ('2018-12-31', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28') group by Stockist_Code having count(distinct Stockist_Code) = 3`

Comment: Got Result.

`select distinct Stockist_Code 
from ZSecondarySales where Tran_date = '2019-02-28' and Stockist_Code in (select distinct Stockist_Code 
from ZSecondarySales where Tran_date = '2019-01-31') and Stockist_Code in (select distinct Stockist_Code 
from ZSecondarySales where Tran_date = '2018-12-31');`